# Photorec recovered directory - asking for missing operand

Tags: photorec

Used Photorec to recover files. They were grouped in a folder " recup_dir.1" in home folder with a lock symbol.
Owner was 'root'
Used chown in the undergiven format to change owner and encountered problem.

$ sudo chown _R $USER:recup_dir.1

Got a response

chown: missing operand after 'recup_dir.1'

Pl help

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is `sudo chown -R $USER: recup_dir.1`

Note the `-R` and the space before the directory name.